# Extracting result returned by google using java code

Tags: java

Can any help me with the Java code to extract results from google search engine for a particular query?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you can get this information from the [Custom Search API,](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) which the [Google API Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) should support just fine.